# Failed to deploy Ionic 4 apps to apk

Tags: android, ionic-framework, apk, ionic4

I tried to deploy my apps (IMOM) to android apk, but there are errors that i don’t understand. I run the code ionic cordova build android , Here is the screenshot of the error.[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bJsr.png) , [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zwO5.png)

anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: I think resource folder is not available in your project directory. Run `ionic cordova resources` command to generate resource in your project.

Comment: Remove the platform and add it again